# How to restrict access to page with php

Tags: php

I can't seem to find a way to block my page from being accessed. I have a page to give tickets to users in mysql, but you can simply type it into http to receive tickets, how do i stop people from doing that??

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
header("refresh:33;url=tickets_give.php" );
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="finessecss.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F9F9F9" background="background3.jpg">

<div class="videobox">

<div class="video"><p>Video Player Unavailable At This Moment</p></div>

<div class="clockbox">
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 30;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown')[0].innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

</script>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is my code for my video page

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "users_database";
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];

if (!(isset($_SESSION['can_accesss']) && $_SESSION['name'] != '')) {
Header("Location:welcome_get.php");
}
unset($_SESSION['can_access']);

// rest of page code
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ('$access' == 'Finesseshopisthebest'){
    ;
}
else{
    echo'mysql' or die;
}

$sql = "UPDATE users_database SET tickets=tickets+10 WHERE username= '$name' and password= '$pass'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    Header("Location:tickets.php");
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

And that is my give tickets page. How do i stop people from going straight to tickets_give.php?

Comment: You will have to provide much more details to receive useful answers

Comment: By adding authentication ;)

Comment: sessions will be your friend

Comment: Pretty broad as is. Maybe `if(some condition) { output content } else { echo 'You aren't authorized'; }`

Comment: @chris85 i cant find a condition to stop people from accessing through http. What do i do for that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a 20-second solution, just check for the presence of a precise query string, eg `yoursite.com/somepage?foo=bar`. If `$_GET["foo"]` is not set, call `exit` and forget about it.

Warning: this is security through obscurity; anyone with a network monitor or even just shoulder surfing would breeze past this, but I guess it's better than nothing. Clearly a smarter, long-term solution is to add meaningful authentication, but it sounds like you have a very short-term problem you need to solve!